# Synchronizing tomcat session timeout with deployed application

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, deployment, liferay, session-timeout

I have deployed an external application (accessed with an html page) in tomcat/webapps and attempting to synchronize it with my Liferay session.  The problem is that the timeouts are not synchronized (specified with the session-timeout property in web.xml), and any activity when accessing this page does not register with Liferay (thus, the timeout does not reset, so I'm always timing out after the amount of time specified in the session-timeout property, defaulted to 60 minutes).

I attempted an explicit call to Liferay.Session.extend() within my html page, and firebug shows that the POST call to extend the session was made, but Liferay still doesn't appear to recognize it.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: is setting `Liferay.Session.autoExtent = true;` before  calling `Liferay.Session.extend();`of any help?

Comment: unfortunately not.  This would never invalidate the session, thus rendering the timeout of no value.  thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Can you post some code? That would help I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work on an application in the liferay, it means you are working on one portlet, until unless you move to another portlet, the liferay session is not reset. so once the 60 min done, you will be automatically timed out.

Whatever you do with in a portlet, it is an ajax call w.r.t Liferay, so the solution would be try to extend the session for every ajax call.

Try putting the following jquery script code in your portlet web page.

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
    A4J.AJAX.AddListener({
        onafterajax : function(req, evt, data) {
            Liferay.Session.setCookie();
        }
    });
});
```

Good luck